# How would I rewrite this form to get Formik working with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

Below is a contrived form example using Formik. When `Field` is in the form, I get the below error when trying to export from Next:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";
import TextInput from "../components/TextInput";
import updateNameForUser from "../utils/updateNameForUser";

const UserForm = (props) => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ name: props.name }}
    onSubmit={(values) => props.updateName(values)}
  >
    {({ handleSubmit }) => (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field name="name" placeholder="name" component={TextInput} />

        <button onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit">
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
    )}
  </Formik>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateName: (values) => dispatch(updateNameForUser(values)),
});
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ name: state.users.name });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserForm);
```

Error:

```
Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

How would this be re-written to use hooks to remove the error?

Here's a [link to a boilerplate codebase](https://github.com/pawel2105/netlify-rewrite-test-nextjs). Git clone and run:

```
npm install
build next && build export
```

Library versions:

- Next: v9.3.5
- Formik: v2.1.2
- React: v16.8.6

Comment: Could you provide an online demo?

Comment: Added link for skeleton codebase.

Comment: I've tried your code (build & export) was success, can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Check this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pawel2105/netlify-rewrite-test-nextjs?file=/pages/index.js

It  works without the error

Comment: That is so weird. I cloned it into a new directory and failed on the export step. What version of node are you using? @aminmohammadi

Comment: @Simpleton i'm using node v12.14.1

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I see it has built and exported correctly on Netlify as well. Must be my environment. So confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to delete this question, but I'll answer it for anyone that searches using the error. The problem was my environment was using the globally installed version of `next` instead of the one from `package.json`.

This happens when you run `next build && next export` directly instead of as a command that you run through an npm script.